# How do I update the table for schema.prisma

Tags: next.js, prisma

I am using Prisma, PlanetScale and Nextjs for my website. Originally I had schema.prisma as follows

```sql
generator client {
    provider        = "prisma-client-js"
    previewFeatures = ["referentialIntegrity"]
}

datasource db {
    provider             = "mysql"
    url                  = env("DATABASE_URL")
    referentialIntegrity = "prisma"
}

model views {
    slug  String @id @db.VarChar(128)
    count BigInt @default(1)
}
```

now i want to insert more table comment in schema.prisma

```sql
model comment {
    id         BigInt   @id @default(autoincrement())
    post       String   @db.VarChar(256)
    email      String   @db.VarChar(256)
    body       String   @db.VarChar(500)
    created_by String   @db.VarChar(256)
    created_at DateTime @default(now()) @db.DateTime(6)
    updated_at DateTime @default(now()) @db.DateTime(6)
}
```

when i run the command `npx prisma db push` is the original data lost or not?

Comment: if `npx prisma db push` anticipates you will lose data, it will either throw an error or require you to accept the data loss. This is well documented in [here](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-migrate/db-push). For your use case, it will be best to use migrations so that you don't lose the data and you can keep track of changes to the schema file.